# How to create a line for range of years in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart

I am new to d3.js. I have some difficulties in rendering a line for the range of year.

Here is the JSON format.

```
var models = [
  {
    model_name: "Sprint 1 (01 Jan - 15 Jan)",
    year: 2020,
    estimated: 50,
    spent: 83,
  },
  {
    model_name: "Sprint 6 (01 Jan - 15 Jan)",
    year: 2020,
    estimated: 67,
    spent: 93,
  },
  {
    model_name: "Sprint 7 (01 Jan - 15 Jan)",
    year: 2020,
    estimated: 56,
    spent: 56,
  }
];
```

Here is the code for x and y scale.

```
var xScale0 = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right])
  .padding(barPadding);
var xScale1 = d3.scaleBand();
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);
xScale0.domain(models.map((d) => d.model_name));
xScale1.domain(["estimated", "spent"]).range([0, xScale0.bandwidth()]);
yScale.domain([
  0,
  d3.max(models, (d) => (d.estimated > d.spent ? d.estimated : d.spent) + 30),
]);
```

This is my xAxis and yAxis code.
I have also attached the example image of how charts are rendered.

[Chart image UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNxxH.png)
I have highlighted the part (red) in the image.

Comment: Your scale is missing domain

Comment: Updated the domain

Comment: Still does not work with domain?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mithun1999/Lk4db5mc  - Code link

Comment: Actually I need to render another custom axis. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNxxH.png  -  I need to render the year as given in the image I attached.